# what's the best way to remove then add a value to a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a sheets that sum the values of multiple parts, let's say:

- part1= 1
- part2= 2
- part3= 3

for each part there is a premium version which is 0.5 higher I leave the choice to the user to say if he wants premium or not

I'd like to know the best way to remove from the sum the price of the part which is not premium and then add the premium (knowing that the premium isn't always 0.5 higher and I have like 15 different parts)

[image: example of the table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B4)*(D2:D4="no")+(C2:C4)*(D2:D4="yes"))
```

[image]